# How to mutate a new tibble column to include a data frame whose name is given as a string in the tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

As part of a wrangling pipeline that involved some `nest`ing and `unnest`ing with `{tidyr}`, I've got an object that looks like that:

```r
library(dplyr)

trb <-
  tibble(data_mtcars      = rep(list(mtcars), 3),
         data_iris        = rep(list(iris), 3),
         data_trees       = rep(list(trees), 3),
         person           = c("lucy", "dan", "john"),
         chosen_data_name = c("data_mtcars", "data_iris", "data_trees"))

trb
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   data_mtcars    data_iris      data_trees    person chosen_data_name
#>   <list>         <list>         <list>        <chr>  <chr>           
#> 1 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> lucy   data_mtcars     
#> 2 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> dan    data_iris       
#> 3 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> john   data_trees
```

And I want to mutate a new column that will include the dataset from either columns `1:3` whose name is given in `chosen_data_name` column.

In other words, I want to utilize the functionality of `get()` to replace string with the object that has the same name. But unlike normal call to `get()`, the object the string refers to is stored *inside the tibble* and not in the global environment (purposely).

Which is why

```r
trb %>% 
  mutate(chosen_data_here = get(chosen_data_name))
```

doesn't work.

How can I mutate a new column in `trb` to get the output:

```r
## # A tibble: 3 x 6
##   data_mtcars    data_iris      data_trees    person chosen_data_name chosen_data_here
##   <list>         <list>         <list>        <chr>  <chr>            <list>          
## 1 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> lucy   data_mtcars      <df [32 x 11]> # mtcars 
## 2 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> dan    data_iris        <df [150 x 5]> # iris 
## 3 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> john   data_trees       <df [31 x 3]>  # trees
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `nest` and `rowwise`:

```
trb %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(nest(get(chosen_data_name), chosen_data_here = everything()))

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  data_mtcars    data_iris      data_trees    person chosen_data_name chosen_data_here  
  <list>         <list>         <list>        <chr>  <chr>            <list>            
1 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> lucy   data_mtcars      <tibble [32 x 11]>
2 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> dan    data_iris        <tibble [150 x 5]>
3 <df [32 x 11]> <df [150 x 5]> <df [31 x 3]> john   data_trees       <tibble [31 x 3]>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is as "automatic" as you might want, but this works:

```
trb %>% 
  mutate(chosen_data_here = case_when(
    chosen_data_name == "data_mtcars" ~ data_mtcars,
    chosen_data_name == "data_iris" ~ data_iris,
    chosen_data_name == "data_trees" ~ data_trees
  ))
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
#   data_mtcars    data_iris      data_trees    person chosen_data_name chosen_data_here
#   <list>         <list>         <list>        <chr>  <chr>            <list>          
# 1 <df [32 × 11]> <df [150 × 6]> <df [31 × 3]> lucy   data_mtcars      <df [32 × 11]>  
# 2 <df [32 × 11]> <df [150 × 6]> <df [31 × 3]> dan    data_iris        <df [150 × 6]>  
# 3 <df [32 × 11]> <df [150 × 6]> <df [31 × 3]> john   data_trees       <df [31 × 3]>
```

Comment: Thanks! But as you implied this method is limited being not very scalable. In my real data I have more than just 3 "chosen_data_names" so it would become tedious.